# CRC Calculation Ignoring Filename (Python 3.5)

Tags: python-3.x, crc

I want to be able to calculate the CRC of a file to be able to check if the file has changed at any point in the future (e.g day 1: filename.txt = A, day 2 filename.txt = B -> File has been changed).

If possible (and this is where I am stuck) I would like to be able to calculate the CRC of a file without taking into account the filename, so as to be able to recognise a filename change (e.g. day 1:filename.txt has CRC value X, day 2: newFileName.txt has CRC value X -> same file, new filename).

I considered a workaround which is to change the filename to something standard before checking the CRC but I wondered if there is a simpler faster way to do this.

Comment: Why not use sha1 or md5 hashes

Comment: A CRC of a file normally doesn't include the file name. You would need to make a special effort to include the file name in the data that the CRC is calculated over.

Comment: I assumed that the filename would influence the output of the algorithm (crc/sha1/md5 etc.). If only the contents of the file are used by the algorithm then 2 files with different filenames but like content would generate the same output. That insight solves my problem nicely - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you.
Still, what you can do:

1. create a dictionary key=filename, value=MD5/SHA1 whatever, say `dict1`
2. create a dictionary key=MD5/SHA1, value=filename, say `dict2`

pickle them, then next check compare the keys and the values of both versions of dict1: if difference in value, file contents has changed
Same thing for dict2: if difference in value, filename has changed, same contents.

What you won't be able to track down, however is filename+filecontents change. You won't be able to see if it's a deletion + new file or rename+change contents. That's the limit.

*Edit*: I was lying about not writing code. I've written some sample code to compute MD5 checksum on the current module (just for demo purposes).

```
import hashlib

with open(__file__,"rb") as f:   # __file__ is full path to current .py file
    contents=f.read()

m = hashlib.md5(contents)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

I get `ebb6e4753cfd7e23dae884a784bc1587` but results may vary depending on line terminations, number of blank lines...

I suggest that you try that yourself, then rename/copy the python file to another one to prove yourself that it does not change. Then add a comment somewhere it will change... Good luck with your project.

*Edit 2: afterthought*: you may read about the Git configuration system. It uses a CRC/MD5 system to check if files changed. I don't know a lot about it, but it may server your purposes without you coding anything.

Comment: Can you confirm what Mark Adler commented above? If yes I can accept the answer (your idea was great but didn't solve my doubt about how to remove the filename from the crc algorythm).